# Do all words that end with "mente" start as adjectives?

Tags: adjetivos, adverbios

I am but a humble beginner in speaking Spanish. No hablo muy bien español.

I equate this new language to a programming language, in which I'm fluent in four and know very well seven.

To understand a programming language, I learn it from a framework-first, words/phrases second approach. I am teaching myself Spanish in the same way.

Today, I researched and documented the nine parts of speech, and while I was working on adverbs, I learned one can make an adverb from an adjective (so long as the adjective can describe an action).

I learned that adding "mente" to an acceptable adjective makes it an adverb. So the adjective "fácil" + "mente" becomes the adverb "fácilmente" (easily).

That said, my question is thus:

Is every word that ends with "mente" this type of adjective compound?

Comment: In principle the answer is YES but just replace "every" by "every that I can think off right now". You know that human languages share with programming languages that they may have unexpected exceptions.

Comment: The big difference between computer languages and natural languages is that natural languages are best learned by informal immersion into the culture while programming languages are best learned by a designed learning process, at least at the beinning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only adjectives in feminine form adverbs if "mente" is added to them. "Fácil" has the same form in masculine and feminine but, if different, the feminine will be used:

- rápido - rápidamente
- lento - lentamente
- severo - severamente
- inesperado - inesperadamente

There are a few words that happen to end in "mente" and are not adverbs, like the second person singular imperative and third person singular present subjunctive of verbs ending in "mentar":

- lamentar - lamente
- comentar - comente
- alimentar - alimente
- fomentar - fomente
- fragmentar - fragmente
- atormentar - atormente
- implementar - implemente
- instrumentar - instrumente
- argumentar - argumente
- fermentar - fermente
- cementar - cemente
- ornamentar - ornamente
- pigmentar - pigmente
- reglamentar - reglamente
- aumentar - aumente
- segmentar - segmente

And some others like:

- demente
- vehemente
- clemente

which are adjectives.

Comment: Buena búsqueda de palabras que no son adverbios!

Comment: Note that "vehementemente" is a valid adverb.

Comment: As are "dementemente" and "clementemente"